# Not all attributes of JavaScript object being mapped into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filepicker.io

I'm using [Inkfilepicker.io](https://www.inkfilepicker.com/) for picture uploading on a project I'm working on.  When you upload a picture, it returns a JavaScript object with some data in it.  I need more, though.  So I query their API using their SDK to get more.  I then add this information to each object.  Lastly, I post these objects using jQuery to process it on the backend.  However, none of the second batch of information goes along for the ride on the backend.  I manually used `JSON.stringify()` to see what the data looked like before it was posted.  The new data was not included.

```
fp.pickAndStore({multiple: true}, {}, function (InkBlobs)
    {
        InkBlobs = $.map(InkBlobs, function(blobio, index)
        {
            fp.stat(blobio, {
                width: true,
                height: true
            }, function(meta) {
                blobio.width = meta.width;
                blobio.height = meta.height;
            });

            return blobio;
        });
        console.log(InkBlobs);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(InkBlobs));
        $.post('/picture', { blobs: InkBlobs }, function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
    });
```

How can I make sure all of the attributes get sent?

**UPDATE**

The string created by the `JSON.stringify()` looks like the following:

```
[{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/PinzEEUlRhSCpc4dYa0w","filename":"browserWars.jpeg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":34284,"key":"Vx1xEuqHTKKCM4hjR6LL_browserWars.jpeg","container":"kandidlypictures","isWriteable":true},{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/wdnWcCUWStiBxbrONeSN","filename":"1440-music-is-the-food.jpg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":97814,"key":"0RrSFSQBTCiifZ8ZkuIj_1440-music-is-the-food.jpg","container":"kandidlypictures","isWriteable":true},{"url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/trdKhlORPCJEu3JRbPYf","filename":"any_browser.jpeg","mimetype":"image/jpeg","size":271194,"key":"1aJNE9MSEyEiAJZAacfD_any_browser.jpeg","container":"kandidlypictures","isWriteable":true}]
```

The expected output should also include a width and height for each object.

Comment: Can you show expected and current outputs?

Comment: jQuery does not call `JSON.stringify` on you `InkBlobs` given as data to the `post()` call, did you expect that?

Comment: What exactly does `InkBlobs` contain? Notice that not all JS data types can be `JSON.stringify`ed, I'm not sure of `Blob`s…

Comment: Yes, Bergi, I did expect it to use `stringify()`.  Even if it doesn't though, it still isn't posting the full object to the backend.  It sends exactly what `stringify()` creates, which is shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate named function:

```
var data = {
           width: true,
           height: true
           };

var fn = function fn(meta)
  {
  blobio.width = meta.width;
  blobio.height = meta.height;

  $.post('/picture', { blobs: InkBlobs }, function(data)
    {
    console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
  };

fp.statSync(blobio, data, fn)
```

Or use `statSync` since `stat` is asynchronous:

```
fp.statSync(blobio, {
                width: true,
                height: true
            }, function(meta) {
                blobio.width = meta.width;
                blobio.height = meta.height;
            });
```

**References**

- [Fun with Named Functions](http://raganwald.com/2014/10/24/fun-with-named-functions)
- [statSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path)